# Formatting custom date fields within channel entries row hook

Tags: templates, add-on-development, date, date-format, parsing

In [Shortlist](http://squarebit.co.uk/addons/shortlist) the {exp:shortlist:view} tag extends the channel->entries() method for it's parsing needs. This works and allows for full custom tag parsing without much extra effort, but runs into issues when formatting extra *date* variables.

In the view loop we provide an extra variable *{entry_real_date}* which is the actual date for the entry (vs. the date it was added to a list). The parser never see's our custom variable as a date variable, so ignores any *format* param.

ie :

```
{entry_real_date format="%n %Y"}
```

is never parsed.

In a normal situation where we're applying our own tag parsing, we'd be able do something like :

```
$tagdata = ee()->TMPL->parse_date_variables($tagdata, $dates);
```

but with in the channel->entries() usage we can't get access to the raw parsing to do this. The parser does look for custom date variables, but only within the context of *custom fields*, so our dynamically attached variable is never handled.

From digging I can find no way to mark our custom variable as a date variable to enable that format parsing.

Has anyone run into this and handled it?

This is on EE2.8+

Comment: Which version of EE?

Comment: 2.8+. (updated the question)

Answer (score 1):

My pragmatic solution would be to just enable PHP on output.

Comment: Agreed; <?php echo strftime("%m/%Y" , intval("{entry_real_date}")); ?> seems to do the trick.

Comment: That works as a hacky work around and I'll add a note to the docs about it, but it would be good if there was a way to get the template parser to pick it up as a valid date field.